# How to dynamically place NSView in relation to NSStatusBar?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsview, nsstatusitem, nsstatusbar

I have created a NSStatusBar NSMenu like this:

```
- (NSMenu *)startUpViewBarMenu {
    NSMenu *menu = [[NSMenu alloc] init];

    NSMenuItem* info = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" action:nil keyEquivalent:@""];
    //[info setTarget:self];
    [info setView:[self startUpView]];
    [menu addItem:info];

    // Disable auto enable
    [menu setAutoenablesItems:NO];
    [menu setDelegate:(id)self];
    return menu;
}
```

I would like to dynamically move the NSView (`[self startUpView]`) that points to where the icon is. Similar to how Evernote has done it. As you can see it is central to the icon: [image]

Whereas with my NSStatusBar the NSView falls either to the left or right of the NSStatusBar icon.

So two questions:

## How can I move the dropdown NSView?

I have tried changing the frame (-100) but it makes no difference:

```
NSView *view = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(-100, 0, 400, 471)];
```

## How can I *dynamically* move the dropdown NSView in relation to the icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evernote does **not** use a menu. This seems to be a NSPopover that is triggered when clicking on your statusitem's view.

```
/* setup your status item */

self.statusItem.highlightMode = YES;
[self.statusItem setAction:@selector(showPopover:)];
[self.statusItem setTarget:put correct target here];


/* use this code to show popover */


 -(void)showPopover:(id)sender
 {
     NSWindow * aWindow = [sender window];
     NSView * aView = [aWindow contentView];
     NSPopover  * aPopover = [[NSPopover alloc] init];
     /* Setup your popover here */
     [aPopover showRelativeToRect:aView.bounds ofView:aView preferredEdge:NSMaxYEdge];
 }
```